# Refresh ng-repeat data

Tags: angularjs

I have a big list containing all of my data, and I have another shorter list containing only the selected data.
Originally, all the data is selected so both lists are identical, and the user must uncheck the checkbox of the unwanted data, and then the unchecked data must disappear from the selected_data_list.

When the page is loaded, the two lists are being filled correctly. But when I uncheck the unwanted data, the selected_data_list is not updating.

I tried to use $scope.$apply(), but it gave me this error:

> Error: $rootScope:inprog
>   Action Already In Progress

Here is my code:

### Complete list:

```
<div ng-controller="BrainRegionsCtrl">

    <div ng-repeat="region in brain_regions">

        <label> 

           <input type="checkbox"
              name="checkbox_brain_region__included"
              id="checkbox_brain_region_{/region.id/}"
              value="{/region.id/}"              
              ng-model="region.show"
              ng-change="update_selected_Brain_regions(region)">                           

           <b>{/region.name/}</b>

         </label>

    </div>
</div>
```

### Selected regions list:

```
<div ng-controller="BrainRegionsCtrl">

    <label ng-repeat="region in selected_brain_regions">
        <input type="radio" name="radio_brain_regions_graphical_search_soma" value="{/region.id/}">
        <b>{/region.name/}</b>
    </label>

 </div>
```

### Controller:

```
ngApp.controller('BrainRegionsCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {

    $scope.brain_regions = [];
    $scope.selected_brain_regions = [];               

    $scope.update_selected_Brain_regions = function (region) {

        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.brain_regions.length; i++) {
            var current_region = $scope.brain_regions[i];
            if (current_region.id === region.id) {
                if (region.show) {
                    $scope.selected_brain_regions.push(current_region);
                }
                else {
                    $scope.selected_brain_regions.splice(i,1);
                }
            }
        }
        console.log($scope.selected_brain_regions);

    };

});
```

Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qc4scy4r/4/)
Thank you.

Comment: can add sample input data

Comment: `ngRepeat` uses **$watchCollection** to detect changes in the collection. It will automatically change the array on update, even asynchronously. Just make sure the array (*selected_brain_regions*) was changed. Debug it, if it's not changing

Comment: Can you check what is value of `region` inside `update_selected_Brain_regions` method? or you can create jsfiddle, will help to understand your issue.

Comment: @AlekseySolovey The (selected_brain_regions) is changing perfectly when unchecking checkboxes in the complete_regions_list. But the selected regions menu is not updating.

Comment: @AvneshShakya the region value is exactly what is should be. I'll try to make a jsfiddle.

Comment: @AvneshShakya I have updated the question added a jsfiddle. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try to use **$rootScope**. 
Because you give the **ng-controller="BrainRegionsCtrl"**  for two div that's why the **$scope.selected_brain_regions** will go to the initial state in the second div.

OR

you should give the **ng-controller="BrainRegionsCtrl"** to the root div which contains the two parts of your code..

Answer (score 1):

Please check with this code and let me know whether it solves your issue. Also please check this working [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/pbyHi8RVSCuscYGpAFDZ?p=preview) of your example scenario.

Template:

```
    <div ng-repeat="region in brain_regions">
        <label>
           <input type="checkbox"
              name="checkbox_brain_region[$index]"
              id="checkbox_brain_region[region.id]"
              value="region.id"              
              ng-model="region.show"
              ng-change="update_selected_Brain_regions(region)">                           
           <b>{{region.name}}</b>
         </label>
    </div>
    <br>
    <label ng-repeat="region in selected_brain_regions">
        <input type="radio" name="radio_brain_regions_graphical_search_soma[$index]"
        ng-model="region.show" value="region.id">
        <b>{{region.name}}</b>
    </label>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.update_selected_Brain_regions = function (region) {
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.brain_regions.length; i++) {
        var current_region = $scope.brain_regions[i];
        if (current_region.id === region.id) {
            if (region.show) {
                $scope.selected_brain_regions.push(current_region);
            } else {
                var index = $scope.selected_brain_regions.map(function(x){ return x.id; }).indexOf(current_region.id);
                $scope.selected_brain_regions.splice(index,1);
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: I have read your code and copied it into my project but it didn't work!!
It doesn't give an error but also doesn't update the list

Comment: Have you looked at my [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/pbyHi8RVSCuscYGpAFDZ?p=preview) example?

Comment: Yea I did. It works online but in my code it didn't :/
I still can't find out the reason

Answer (score 0):

AngularJS promises already call .apply() on their callbacks. You cannot call .apply again inside the callbacks since they're already being .applied, and the error "In Progress" tells exactly that. Just remove the .apply call and it will work, unless you have further errors.

Comment: Yea I know. I just tried it and it gave me the error and then I removed it. I just mentioned it to let you guys know that I have already tried it.

Comment: There is another option to emulate a click on an object through jQuery. It worked with me though it was not quite correct

Answer (score 0):

Your issue because of index update, so try `track by $index`, should work.

```
<label ng-repeat="region in selected_brain_regions track by $index">
    <input type="radio" name="radio_brain_regions_graphical_search_soma" value="{{region.id}}">
    <b>{{region.name}}</b>
</label>
```

Check out [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/avnesh2/yn00uzL9/2/)

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work.
In my code it just had no affect but in jsfiddle, it gave an error.