# Splice not working Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

i want remove elements from object array but splice is not working. nay help will be appreciated.

```
function successCallback(data){

    console.log(Object.keys($scope.tempresult).length)
    if (Object.keys($scope.tempresult).length>0){
        console.log(data.data.length)
        $scope.tempresult.splice(1,Object.keys($scope.tempresult).length)
        $scope.$apply
        for (i=0;i<=data.data.length;i++){
            $scope.tempresult.push(data.data[i])
        }
        $scope.tempresult=data.data
    }
    else{
        $scope.tempresult=data.data
    }
    console.log(typeof $scope.tempresult)
    console.log(typeof data.data)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got the solution, i was giving controller name to two div so it was not refreshing the ng-repeat div. Refer attached link [Refresh ng-repeat data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47630956/refresh-ng-repeat-data)